# IndexOutOfRangeException SqlCommand .NET

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I want to create an application which will create a `.CSV` file with data from my database but I get this error :

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException : 'CT_Num'

And when I remove :

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT [Actionnaire Pal] FROM f_comptet";
```

and

```
dataReader["[Actionnaire Pal]"].ToString()
```

I don't get any errors anymore.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        SqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();

        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT CT_Num, [Actionnaire Pal] FROM F_COMPTET WHERE CG_NumPrinc = '4110000'";

        SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\facture.csv");

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            sw.WriteLine("FAAV" + ";" + "." + ";" + "02" + ";" + "JJ/MM/AAAA" + ";" + "A" + ";" + "11" + ";" + dataReader["CT_Num"].ToString() + dataReader["[Actionnaire Pal]"].ToString() + ";");
        }
            sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You only execute the second CommandText statement. You overwrote the first one and therefore CT_Num doesn't exist. So when you remove that second one, the first is executed. Perhaps you're wanting to join the two tables?

Comment: Oh, I see this is the same table, just fix your query to include both columns `SELECT CT_Num, [Actionnaire Pal] FROM f_comptet WHERE CG_NumPrinc = '4110000'`

Comment: Also, when using the index operator of `SqlDataReader` you do not need to escape spaces.  E.g. do `dataReader["Actionnaire Pal"].ToString()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do not know if it's a problem to join two tables but even with data from the same table I have the same error

Comment: Also, off-topic but why are you concatenating static strings instead of just `"FAAV;.;02;JJ/MM/AAAA..."`?

Comment: I rectified the request because I use the same table but I still have the same error

Comment: Have you ran that query in SSMS and looked at what is returned?

Comment: "I still have the same error"...**exactly** the same? It seems very unlikely based on the revised code. See my answer below, it seems more likely to be the problem. Are you sure the out of range is not related to this field instead? I really can't see how adding another field could cause the CT_Num field not to be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
dataReader["[Actionnaire Pal]"]
```

to

```
dataReader["Actionnaire Pal"]
```

The `[` and `]` just tell SQL to make a column name from everything within them, and disregard the spaces (which normally it would consider to denote the start of the next part of the statement). They don't actually form part of the final column name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but when I add a data from another table I have the same error, `System.IndexOutOfRangeException : 'CT_Num'`. I have to join the tables in my request ?

Comment: Can I add this `SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT CT_Num, [Actionnaire Pal] FROM    F_COMPTET where CG_NumPrinc = '4110000'";
command.CommandText = "SELECT D_CodeRegion FROM p_dossier";` and `dataReader["D_CodeRegion"].ToString()`

Comment: That's not how you join tables. All you are doing there is declaring a query in the first statement, and then declaring another, **entirely separate** query which **overwrites** the first one. The first one never gets executed. You simply replaced one string with another in the CommandText property. Charles already explained that to you in the very first comment on the question. If there is a relation between the two tables, write a single SQL statement using a JOIN operator to combine the results together. If they are unrelated, you need to execute two separate queries.

Comment: The `CommandText` property is a simple string. You give it a SQL query to execute. It stores that value until you run the ExecuteReader method - at that moment it executes whatever is in the `CommandText` property. If you change the CommandText property's value many times before you run ExecuteReader, then it only ever executes the last value you changed it to, because that's what it finds there at the moment that ExecuteReader runs. It is not an array containing multiple queries. Even if it _was_, the result would be multiple different dataReaders, so your code would still fail.

Comment: I understand better and I create two separate queries, thank you for your explanations. I also have several datareader and I have this error : **A DataReader associated with this Command is already open. It must first be closed.**

Comment: you can google all these errors quite easily you know - just paste the error text into the search engine and you'll get lots of forum posts about it, but anyway basically it means you have to close the first datareader in the Command before you can use the second one. Or if that's not practical due to the way you're processing the results, then just use two entirely separate SqlCommand objects.

Comment: Anyway none of this is directly relevant to your original question, which I have answered, so if it helped you please mark it Accepted (click the tick next to the question so it turns green) - thanks